# Julia: how to compute a particular operation on certain columns of a Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, mean

I have the following Dataframe

```
using DataFrames, Statistics
df = DataFrame(name=["John", "Sally", "Kirk"], 
               age=[23., 42., 59.],
               children=[3,5,2], height = [180, 150, 170])

print(df)

3×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ name   │ age     │ children │ height │
│     │ String │ Float64 │ Int64    │ Int64  │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ John   │ 23.0    │ 3        │ 180    │
│ 2   │ Sally  │ 42.0    │ 5        │ 150    │
│ 3   │ Kirk   │ 59.0    │ 2        │ 170    │
```

I can compute the mean of a column as follow:

```
println(mean(df[:4]))
166.66666666666666
```

Now I want to get the mean of all the numeric column and tried this code:

```
x = [2,3,4]
for i in x
  print(mean(df[:x[i]]))
end
```

But got the following error message:

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Symbol, ::Int64)

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./In[64]:3
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: as a general comment - very soon `df[col]` syntax will be deprecated. So in a few days a recommended pattern will be `df[!, col]` to access column without copying it and `df[:, col]` to copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the `DataFrame`'s column using an integer index specifying the column's position. You should just use the integer value without any `:` before `i`, which would create the symbol `:i` but you do not a have column named `i`.

```
x = [2,3,4]
for i in x
  println(mean(df[i])) # no need for `x[i]`
end
```

You can also index a `DataFrame` using a `Symbol` denoting the column's name.

```
x = [:age, :children, :height];

for c in x
    println(mean(df[c]))
end
```

---

You get the following error in your attempt because you are trying to access the `i`th index of the symbol `:x`, which is an undefined operation.

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Symbol, ::Int64)
```

Note that `:4` is just `4`.

```
julia> :4
4

julia> typeof(:4)
Int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner that actually selects all `Number` columns:

```
julia> mean.(eachcol(df[findall(x-> x<:Number, eltypes(df))]))
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  41.333333333333336
   3.3333333333333335
 166.66666666666666
```

For many scenarios `describe` is actually more convenient:

```
julia> describe(df)
4×8 DataFrame
│ Row │ variable │ mean    │ min  │ median │ max   │ nunique │ nmissing │ eltype   │
│     │ Symbol   │ Union…  │ Any  │ Union… │ Any   │ Union…  │ Nothing  │ DataType │
├─────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────┼────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ name     │         │ John │        │ Sally │ 3       │          │ String   │
│ 2   │ age      │ 41.3333 │ 23.0 │ 42.0   │ 59.0  │         │          │ Float64  │
│ 3   │ children │ 3.33333 │ 2    │ 3.0    │ 5     │         │          │ Int64    │
│ 4   │ height   │ 166.667 │ 150  │ 170.0  │ 180   │         │          │ Int64    │
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question `println(mean(df[4]))` works as well (instead of `println(mean(df[:4]))`).

Hence we can write

```
x = [2,3,4]
for i in x
  println(mean(df[i]))
end
```

which works